# How to insert Date values in Table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have created this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE HUL 
(
   Company_name varchar(50),
   Purchase_date date,
   Quantity int,
   Price float,
   Age int,
   profit_and_loss float
)
```

While I am trying to insert date values am getting an error. Am providing the insert query I have tried and the error as well

```sql
INSERT INTO HUL (Company_name, Purchase_date, Quantity, Price, Age, profit_and_loss)
VALUES ('Hindusthan_Unilever', '25-03-2022', 1, 1950.40, 125, 669.45);
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```sql
INSERT INTO HUL (Company_name, Purchase_date, Quantity, Price, Age, profit_and_loss)
VALUES ('Hindusthan_Unilever', (CAST('25032022', AS DATE)), 1, 1950.40, 125, 669.45);
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

```sql
INSERT INTO HUL (Purchase_date) 
VALUES ('25-03-2022');
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can any one please me get the right query to fix this in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: `'20220325'` (`yyyyMMdd`) is an unambiguous format (as is `2022-03-25` -- for `DATE`, but not other date/time types). Other formats depend on regional settings, so they're not advisable. For non-constant values you can also consider `DATEFROMPARTS` (and appropriately typed parameters, of course).

Comment: If you just want to hard code values in sql scripts then write the dates using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation which is `yyyy-MM-dd`. If this is coming from an application or script you plan on writing then make sure you are using parameters and it becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will happily parse strings into dates if they meet a certain set of formats.

Some of those formats depend upon your regional settings. For example, people in some parts of the world (mostly the USA) seem to like dates in month-day-year format, aka MM-dd-yyyy.

In other, slightly more sensible parts of the world people are used to day-month-year format, aka dd-MM-yyyy. This is what you are currently using.

But which of those SQL will accept depends on the regional settings of the system. It can't just accept both, because what would '01-02-2022' mean? Is it the first of Febrary, or the second of January? How can SQL Server know what you meant?

Then there are formats which are unambiguous. They only get interpreted one way no matter what your regional settings are. The simplest example is yearMonthDay, ie, yyyyMMdd. If you provide this format then the interpretation doesn't depend upon your regional settings. The value '20220201' is always interpreted as "the first of February".

So that explains the problem with your first query and your third query. In your second query you have an unnecessary comma. To fix the syntax error...

```sql
cast('25032022', AS DATE) -- no good, syntax error
cast('25032022' AS DATE) -- comma removed
```

But this would be interpreted as the value "22nd day of the 20th month (??) in the year 2503", because you have the numbers the wrong way around.

If *necessary* <sup>*</sup> you *can* force SQL to interpret text the way you want using `set dateformat`. Example:

```sql
set dateformat mdy; -- tell sql to read the text as month then day then year
select cast('01-02-2022' as date); -- SQL will now read this as January 2 2022

set dateformat dmy; -- now tell it to read it as day then month then year
select cast('01-02-2022' as date); -- now it's February 1, 2022
```

You can also "force" a particular interpretation using [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with a style argument, or [`try_parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with a culture.

<sup>* "Necssary" here meaning "you might not have the option of changing the incoming format, because developers aren't normally the ones adding data, users are, and you could be receiving the data in a csv, or by some other mechanism over which you have no control, but from which you still need to ingest"</sup>

Comment: `DATEFORMAT` should basically never be used, because it's a global solution to a local problem -- the setting persists on the connection and may creep into places that aren't expecting it to deviate from the default. Unless you're willing and able to stick it *everywhere*, that's asking for trouble -- unnecessary trouble, since using ISO-8601 always works, and if you have a non-ISO format, you can use the third parameter of `CONVERT`. Best to forget all about it and use one of the [safe literal formats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/), always.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't disagree, hence the, "if necessary", but I'll add `convert` and `try_parse` as well.

Comment: The problem with the "if necessary" is that it's one of those things where, if you *know* you need it and it's a valid solution to your particular problem, you're already clever enough to use it responsibly. If you're not, it looks like a great "quick fix" that'll instead come back to bite you, when the alternatives won't. The quick fix for the OP is writing `20220325` instead of `25-03-2022` and moving on.

Comment: @JeroenMostert "If necessary" aka "you might not have the option of changing the incoming format, because developers aren't normally the ones adding data, users are, and you could be receiving the data in a csv, or by some other mechanism over which you have no control, but from which you still need to ingest".

Comment: @marc_s `datetime` doesn't appear anywhere in this question, or in my answer.

Comment: I would be perfectly OK with writing *that* instead of "if necessary"! `DATEFORMAT` should really be the last resort if you have to solve it all in T-SQL -- when ingesting CSV, for example, you'd be mad if you didn't have a piece of software processing it, which would also be free to parse dates.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Would you? My first port of call would be `bulk insert`.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. `BULK INSERT` requires the CSV file to be readable from the server, which more often than not is not possible in a properly firewalled setup. It also requires that it's actually a file `BULK INSERT` can read -- so no fancy quoting, mismatched headers or any other of the myriad problems that often plague CSV (and heaven help you if have to diagnose the problems if it just silently mangles the input for you on inserting). I would normally sail right past that port and go for a client-driven bulk insert operation, even if it's just the import/export wizard...

Comment: ...but all of this is tangential to "don't use `SET DATEFORMAT` unless it's your only option, because despite the drawback of being a global setting it *still* can't solve all problems with date formats".

Comment: Welp, I've done a few thousand bulk inserts from user files/spreadsheets over the past 20 years, the last time I wrote a program to do the ingestion was.... I don't even remember. If you want to die on the "nobody should be using bulk insert" hill, though... <shrug>. Fair enough.

Comment: I have no imminent desire to die, much less on a hill. I suspect this is one of those cases where people have learned different lessons from the different experiences they've had, and that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to understand here is different cultures and languages have different expectations around how dates are formatted.

SQL is no different. It is its own language, and just like any other language it has its own native date format for string literals. When writing SQL, it’s *wrong* to put your own cultural expectations into this very different language.

So for dates in SQL Server, the correct format is `yyyMMdd` (no separators). For dates with a time component, there are two accepted formats: `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]` and `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`. Anything else is **not correct** and there are times of the year when the value will be interpreted incorrectly.

---

Of course, this assumes you're including the the value as a literal in the string. If you're building this string in client code, **it is never okay to use string concatenation to include these values in the SQL** in the first place. Instead, you must **always use parameterized queries/prepared statements**.

Done properly, this means a strongly-typed `datetime` object in whatever client platform you prefer, assigned to a strong-typed `DateTime` parameter value sent directly to the server, such that the datetime value is *never at any point even converted to a string*.

> https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/

Answer (score -3):

In SQL Server insert into keyword is used to add up some values in a table.

```
INSERT INTO HUL 
(
    Company_name, 
    Purchase_date,
    Quantity,
    Price,
    Age,
    profit_and_loss
)
VALUES 
(
    'A Worldwide Company',
    '28-07-2022',
    1000,
    175.20,
    35,
    70.50
)
```

Comment: `28-07-2022` is actually a complicated way of writing `-2001`, since it'll be parsed as two subtractions. This will not convert to a `DATE` value. Even if you added quotes, you'd just be back to the same problem the OP had in the first place, which is that parsing `'28-07-2022'` depends on regional settings.

Comment: To format code, use either indentation (four spaces) or three backticks (```). Not single quotes. (Though no matter how you format it, this isn't answering the question.)

Comment: backticks, not single quotes. But this still isn't right. The date is still very wrong for the already mentioned reasons, and the price value will not parse properly.